# ssh tunnel and oracle

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, oracle

On oracle server i can connect clear

```
sqlplus  user/pass@hostremote/SID
```

If i make a tunnel

```
ssh -L 1521:localhost:1521 -F -n hostremote -vvv
```

give me

```
debug1: Connection to port 1521 forwarding to localhost port 1521 requested.
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1521 for localhost port 1521, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 60882 to 127.0.0.1 port 1521, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS: connection close
```

Why?

Usually i do ssh tunnel on directly connected server,for example

```
ORACLESERVER=192.168.0.15
CLIENT=192.168.0.4
```

On client i make the tunnel and connect with sqlplus on localhost,easy.

The situation now is a little different and more complex

```
PSHYSICAL SERVER=192.168.0.44
VIRTUALMACHINE WITH NAT=192.168.0.45 eth0 10.3.1.1 eth1
ORACLESERVER=virtual machine 10.3.1.4
```

I have make a DNAT on VIRTUALMACHINE,i can 
use telnet 1521 VIRTUALMACHINE
and tcptraceroute 1521 return succesfully connection.
But after tunnel(succesfully) i have TNS error and no
connection.

This is the dnat make with firewalld

```
 forward-ports: port=1521:proto=tcp:toport=1521:toaddr=10.3.1.4
    port=1521:proto=udp:toport=1521:toaddr=10.3.1.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Oracle opens additional connections, not to port 1521, after the initial connection, so your tunnel won't work this way. Set up Oracle Connection Manager on the server side so you can do all your talking to it and have it do multiple connections inside the server network.

Oracle docs (not public): https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=Note:361284.1
Open, uhh, mirror: http://blog.itpub.net/161195/viewspace-1053131/

Answer (score 1):

- Oracle TCP protocol is not wired. In some situations it behaves similarly as FTP. e.i. it might open additional TCP connections on dynamically allocated port.
- Oracle TCP protocol uses OOB bit in TCP header. This sometimes might cause problems when wrapping TCP into TCP.

Most probably you have problems with the 1st one point. Use `strace`/`tcpdump` to find out whether `sqlplus` is trying to open 2nd connection.

Comment: I forgot to add something about network situation, i add now,usually i do ssh tunnel sucessfully on simple net connection(direct)