# Tunnel fails with "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" and ORA-12537 or ORA-12514

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, oracle-database

Here is what I did:

1/ Establish connection from my client PC to jump with tunnel in putty with:

```
L2234 ('Source port')  
localhost:2235 ('Destination')
```

2/ Once logged onto this jump server, in same terminal log to destination DB server with:
a) `ssh db_server.domain.com -L 2235:127.0.0.1:1521`

or:
b) `ssh db_server.domain.com -L 2235:db_server.domain.com:1521`

3/ From my client PC trying to establish SQL*Plus connection using string:
`conn system@"(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=2234)))(connect_data=(service_name=db_svc_name)))"`

fails with
`ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed`

when I used ssh first option above (with "127.0.0.1"), or fails with:
`ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

when I ssh'ed using DB server name.

I can't understand why it fails cause *from my jump machine* when using Oracle client installed there I can connect with connect string:
`conn system@"(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=db_server.domain.com)(port=1521)))(connect_data=(service_name=db_svc_name)))"`

(so connection through port 1521 between jump <-> DB server is OK)

Any idea ?? Are there config parameters somewhere that have an impact on this ? If yes, on which machine should I have a look ?

Comment: if I understand you are trying to use a tunnel to a tunnel, right? why not mapping the port directly on the client passing the connection by the jump server, since it got access to the port of the DB?

something like this: ssh -L localhost:1521:db_server.domain.com:1521 user@jumpserver

Comment: AFAIK TNS uses more than one port (ie not just 1521 to work). See this question. Probably the same issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243328/ssh-tunnel-and-oracle